# Geometry Nodes - decrease scale and minimum spacing as Z increases

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a mid-poly pine tree. I have a spine as the core object, distributing points on surface, and using a round-end cylinder as the branch instance. Trouble is, I want them to get smaller and closer together the higher they go. How can I link their Z-position to both the scale of the instance and the DistanceMin? I saw another answer here advising use of the CaptureAttribute node, but I don't seem to be operating it properly. Thanks in advance[image]
[image]

Comment: This would be a quite complex answer and rather require a tutorial. Just search for "plants", "trees" or "flowers" and "geometry nodes" on Youtube, there are loads of tutorials. Here some examples: [Pine trees in 3.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URWuNhg5ZNk), [Plants for beginners in 3.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uslTaqiv_7k&t=962s), [Plant growth with fields 3.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSkaM-8Vgz8&t=6s)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: i think you are the right man for complex answers! ;D

Comment: and i personally think it is not very complex...i will try ;)

Comment: As a quick result with the given nodetree, sure. But I think watching those tutorials would give a better understanding to build something like that on one's own. And well... me and complex answers... depends on my mood and time.

Comment: not my day today.....i cannot believe i tried it for hours now and still didn't got it working...need coffee...! Robin !? :D

Comment: @Chris Maybe you should watch some tutorials :D

Comment: That’s what I do all day long….and yes, you are right!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann : See ? I was right! It’s not complex, just complex for you and me  Robin made this in 3 mins! He must have had great coffee!

Answer (score 2):

Keeping this as simple as possible. If you start with a curve, (which can always be converted) it gives you a *Spline Parameter*. 0 at one end, and 1 at the other. A function of that can be taken to determine the position and scale of instances initially made on its points, but shuffled up or down it by the function.

Either math-y:

[image]

Or manual:

[image]

with this sort of result:

[image]

These groups have been kept small for illustration, but if necessary, the attributes can be captured and transferred to any mesh derived from the curve.

Comment: You are still my hero….! +1

Comment: @Chris thanks :/   ... but I wonder if this enough? I'll expand it to some sort of pine-tree when I've got some time.

Comment: That's what I mean... simply scaling along a curve isn't the problem. But if that makes a pleasing pine tree...?

Comment: They'll be viewed from a distance, surrounding a scene. Since I'm better at drawing than modeling, my plan is to rough model my animation, and use grease pencil to rotoscope everything. The tree upgrade is intended to show clusters of the pine branches that will respond to shadow. Thanks all for your input!